# Novel where a kingdom is attacked by a gigantic shadow

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a fantasy Book about 10 or so years ago that I really want to find again. I will try and list as much info as I can remember about the book.

The Book had a medieval Tone.
A kingdom is being attacked by monsters coming from a massive shadow spreading over the land. The king of the kingdom gets stabbed by one of the main characters that has been "possessed" (he can hear the monsters' thoughts somehow) by the shadow and he takes over the throne. The new king leads his people to another kingdom to escape the shadow (the other kingdom might be an elven kingdom).

Somehow, the king is helping the "shadow" to save Himself; the king sends one of the army's heroic soldiers to a mountain where he gets turned into stone.

The same warrior is also considered a primary character of the book (I think along with a girl as well).

Answer (score 6):

After some more searching I realised why I couldn't find the book I was looking for. I was looking for an English book, while in fact it was a Swedish book called *[Den Stora Freden Krig](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilogin_om_Frihetskrigen)* (The Big War for Peace) by Niklas Krog.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you should mark it as “Accepted” (click the green tick mark next to the vote count).